# Why Cant I Get My CSV File Formatted Correctly?

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv

So I have a small VBA application that is meant to take input via a userform then send that data to a CSV file. When i read the data from the split userform textboxes the data will not format as it shows in the resulting excel file. I did some research into this and found that saving as CSV causes this to happen sometimes so i set up a script to show the value of each line in the text box and even if i don't save as a CSV the extra characters are still there. I'm hoping someone on here can tell me why this is happening.

I have tried creating a blank CSV file then writing the data to it

I have tried using a for next loop to grab all the data from the userform without saving it but the characters are still present

I have tried printing to a text file then renaming as CSV

The csv file the code generates looks great and perfect but when i copy the cells to a text file I get extra characters that should not be there. This is the output I get when copying the cells to a text file

```
Operation Type  Full Name   S ID    Group ID    Email Address   Phone Number    Extension   BO Flag CFlag   FFlag   MD List Locale
N   "Test 1
"   "Test.1
"   GroupTest   "Test1@test.com
"   "0000000000
"       Yes No  No      en_US
N   "Test 2
"   "Test.2
"   GroupTest   "Test2@test.com
"   "0000000000
"       Yes No  No      en_US
N   Test 3  Test.3  GroupTest   Test3@test.com  "0000000000
"       Yes No  No      en_US
```

for some reason the last row is formatted correctly but I can't figure out why the rest of the rows are not

It should contain a single row for each user like the below

```
Operation Type  Full Name   S ID    Group ID    Email Address   Phone Number    Extension   BO Flag CFlag   FFlag   MD List Locale
N   Test 1  Test.1  GroupTest   Test1@test.com  0000000000      Yes No  No      en_US
N   Test 2  Test.2  GroupTest   Test2@test.com  0000000000      Yes No  No      en_US
```

This is how I am pulling the data from the textbox

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls

    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then

        If ctrl.Name = "TextBox1" Then 'Full Name

                UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus

                LCount = UserForm1.TextBox1.LineCount

                BoxValue = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text

                For i = 0 To LCount - 1

                    BoxValue = Split(UserForm1.TextBox1, Chr(10))(i)

                    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i + 2).value = BoxValue

                Next i

        End If

   End If

Next ctrl
```

This has to be something related to how I'm pulling data from the textbox but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that all i needed to do was use a different split delimiter

I switched from: 
BoxValue = Split(UserForm1.TextBox1, **Chr(10)**)(i)

To: 
BoxValue = Split(UserForm1.TextBox4, **vbCrLf**)(i)

This causes the split function to split at every return and now my data is perfectly formatted.

Hope this helps someone out there